# VB.NET Suggestion for optimizing my code for this function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, optimization, query-optimization

Can you suggest me on what to do to optimize my code. 
As you can see in the picture i am displaying all of the student grades on each subject in a textbox and there are total of 51 textbox.

[image]

In my database i have sub_id 1 to 51 and i am repeating the same query 51 times for sub_id 1 to 51 for certain student. 
Here is what exactly my code is

```
query = "SELECT grade " & _
       " FROM student_subject" & _
       " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
       " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = 1 AND enrolled = 1 "

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        textbox_Sub1.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
        dr.Close()
    End If

    query = "SELECT grade " & _
       " FROM student_subject" & _
       " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
       " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = 2 AND enrolled = 1 "

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        textbox_Sub2.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
        dr.Close()
    End If

    query = "SELECT grade " & _
      " FROM student_subject" & _
      " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
      " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = 3 AND enrolled = 1 "

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        textbox_Sub3.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
        dr.Close()
    End If

    query = "SELECT grade " & _
      " FROM student_subject" & _
      " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
      " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = 4 AND enrolled = 1 "

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        textbox_Sub4.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
        dr.Close()
    End If
```

**EDIT UPDATE:**

```
'** DECLARTING ALL VARIABLES NEEDED
Public GetStudentNum As String
Dim connstring As String = "Data Source=localhost;Database=csais;User ID=root;Password=;"
Dim myconn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connstring)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
Dim query


'**START FORM LOAD
Private Sub flow1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetStudentNum = enrollStd.tempStudentNum
    myconn.Open()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 51
        query = "SELECT grade " & _
        " FROM student_subject" & _
        " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
        " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = " & i.ToString() & " AND enrolled = 1 "

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find("textbox_Sub" & i.ToString(), True)(0), TextBox)
            tb.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
            dr.Close()
        End If
    Next

    myconn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a loop for this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 51
    query = "SELECT grade " & _
   " FROM student_subject" & _
   " INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
   " where student_subject.student_id='" & GetStudentNum & "' AND sub_id = " & i.ToString() & " AND enrolled = 1 "

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find("textbox_Sub" & i.ToString(), True)(0), TextBox)
        tb.Text = dr.Item("grade").ToString
        dr.Close()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I am getting an error in the line 
dr = cmd.executeReader 

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

I edited my code with your code. 
I don't think i have a opendata  reader thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I Fixed it  I move the dr.close() after end IF

Comment: @preciousbetine Hitting the database 50 times is not a great solution. Especially with UI involvement. Get all the data. Dump it in a DataTable and search there for what you need.